# How to convert string extracted by regex to integer in python?

Tags: python, regex

i'm trying to convert string to integer, but it's not that so easier than i'm thinking.

```
content = '''
<entry colname="1" morerows="1" morerowname="2"><p>111</p></entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="2"><p></p></entry>'''


morerows = ''.join(re.findall('morerows="\d"', content))
morerows_n = int(''.join(re.findall('\d', morerows)))
print(morerows_n)
```

this results error as follow :

```
morerows_n = int(''.join(re.findall('\d', morerows)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

where is wrong with that code? 
i've tried int() function but doesn't work and it's not float also.

any help?

Comment: It results in `1` for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are non-integer characters in the morerows attribute in your real case.

```
How about this:

content = '''
<entry colname="1" morerows="1x" morerowname="2"><p>111</p></entry>
<entry colname="1" morerows="1" morerowname="2"><p>111</p></entry>
<entry colname="2" rowname="2"><p></p></entry>'''

morerows = ''.join(re.findall('morerows="[0-9]+"', content))
if morerows:
    morerows_n = int(''.join(re.findall('\d', morerows)))
print(morerows_n)
```

Use `[0-9]+` instead of `\d`

Comment: I found what it's wrong with , yes you're right! some attributes have no morerows=" attribute in real case. so i use try and except. lot of thanks!

Comment: and i guess it's better to use \d than [0-9] cuz this number can be over 10. anyway thank you